# How to create common gradle project used by other projects

Tags: java, gradle, module

I have a gradle project that consist of 3 parts: client, common and service.
There are some classes that are used both in client project and service project, therefore I wanted to create a common module and build a jar from it and then import it in other two projects as a library. I put shared classes in common module, I didnt create the main class because I want to project to only provide other classes, so it looks like this:

[image]

Then I tried to import it in other project as a library and build them, but when I try to build it with gradle it throws a bunch of errors about the classes from common module:
[image]

I couldnt find any tutorials online how to make a common module with gradle. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you import the common library in other project? Build files would be useful. Also how do you really build the common lib?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all three modules are part of the same multi-module build then in `client\build.gradle` and `service\build.gradle` you add:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':common')
}
```

The `project(:module)` syntax is described in [Project dependencies docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies).

However if `common`, `client` and `service` are separate projects and don't share the same root `build.gradle` you have to publish the `common` module into a shared repository and use it like any regular dependency. Easiest to do with Maven Local repository.

Comment: OP said "I tried to import it in other project as library", so I thought the common project isn't a module but an external project (otherwise what you says is good).

Comment: it is one multiproject, but when I add this line and try to run dependencies, it tells me that the project ':common' couldnt be found in root project 'service'.

Comment: I did it and it throws this error:Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'client'.

Answer (score 2):

In Gradle, modules/subprojects must be included to the `settings.gradle` file in root project to make it a part of the whole project.
You can add the module to `settings.gradle` similarly to:

```
rootProject.name = 'gradle-root-project'
include('common') //this adds the module
```

Later, either the root build script or other modules, if they want to use the `common` module classes, they need to declare the `common` as their dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    //...
}
```

For example, if you will have another module in the project, let's say `client` and this module needs to use the code from the `common` module, then the `client` module must be included in the `settings.gradle` file of the root project and added as dependency to the `build.gradle` script of the `client` module.

If someone reading that would still similar problems when configuring multimodile projects, then it would be good to check this question [Why gradle removes dependency when I build a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686666/why-gradle-removes-dependency-when-i-build-a-project/60686858#60686858), it has a bit longer and more detailed explanation of what might be going on underneath Gradle/IDE project configurations.

If you are going to work more with Gradle, you could take a look at [this article](https://blog.j-labs.pl/understanding-gradle) about overall insight on Gradle.

Comment: @McLovin please, accept this or Karols answer to question (upvote if possible, especially Karols answer), it may help future seekers to find a solution or restain others from trying to answer a question that already was answered. The thing that Karol staded would be enough and a proper answer if rest of the project would be configured properly, I'm saying, there was not enough details to give a final working solution. Overall, I'm just thinking of keeping SO clean, ie accept Karols one and at the bottom of question add link to your next question about it. No must, just asking, thanks.