# Why gradle removes dependency when I build a project

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have no idea why gradle is doing this to me. I have a multiproject that looks like this:

```
|Parent
 |client
 |common
 |service
```

Parent is just an empty project and client, common and service are gradle java projects:
I have some classes that are used in both client and service, therefore I wanted to create a common project and build a jar that I would later use in both service and client. I can build the common jar, but whenever i try to do 'add dependency on common' and then try to 'refresh gradle', it removes the dependency and fails to build!
This is what I do:
[image]

Then I press this because I want to build it:
[image]

And it just removes the dependency!!!

[image]

This is build.gradle file from client project:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

group = 'sot.rest'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
}
```

Please help, Im desperate!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my answer on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685569/how-to-create-common-gradle-project-used-by-other-projects/60686682#60686682). It should give you an idea how to structure and declare the multi-module gradle projects.

I think that when you add the dependency on module with IntelliJ, it just adds it to the project structure through project settings in IntelliJ. And later, when you hit refresh, IntelliJ configures the project based on Gradle files.

To make it working, the Parent project should also be a Gradle project. If it isn't just add `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` under the Parent directory.
Then in `settings.gradle` add the subprojects like:

```
rootProject.name = 'Parend'
include('common') //this adds the module
include('client')
include('service')
```

And later, in `build.gradle` files of `client` and `service` modules add the `common` module as dependency with:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    //...
}
```

If you are going to work more with Gradle, you could take a look at [this article](https://blog.j-labs.pl/understanding-gradle) about overall insight on Gradle.

Edit:
(I understood that when you use `implementation` it doesn't throw errors)

To work with multimodule project with Gradle, the root project also needs to be a Gradle project. The root might or might not contain any source code, but it needs to have its own Gradle files.
So if your project structure needs to be like:

```
Root project 'parent'
+--- Project ':client'
+--- Project ':common'
\--- Project ':service'
```

Then the `parent` and submodule projects need to be set as Gradle projects.
To make it the `parent` project needs to have at least a `settings.gradle` file and declared includes for submodules, similarly to:

```
rootProject.name = 'parent' 
include 'common'
include 'client'
include 'service'
```

Each of modules (`client`,`common`,`service`) must have a `build.gradle` files under its directory. Submodules using `common`, so the `service` and `client` must add the `common` as dependency in their own `build.gradle` files, like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    //and rest of required dependencies
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Then you should be able to import public classes from `common` in those submodules and rebuild or reimport project without error.

Since the `parent` project doesn't contain any source code, then it doesn't need its own build script, but then build file of all of the submodules needs to declare the java plugin on top of the build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

Since you are working with IntelliJ and your project could have different structure previously, then the project structure in IntelliJ setting could be messed up now.
To fix it you could go to File->Project Structure->Modules and remove/reimport the parent module again.

If you don't have many classes now, I'd recommend you to create a new project. In the "New Project" window pick Gradle and uncheck Java in "Additional Libraries and Frameworks". This will create blank Gradle project.
After the project is generated, do a right mouse click on `parent`, and select New->Module. In new module window again pick Gradle and leave the Java checked (since the submodules will contain source code).
With that, the IntelliJ will automatically include created module to the `settings.gradle` file of root/parent project and the build file of that module will contain the basic configuration (e.g. the java plugin).
But you still add the dependency of one module in another in the `build.gradle` file of that module.

Comment: I cannot put implementation project anywhere because it throws this error:Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':common'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I did it and it throws this error: Project with path ':common' could not be found in root project 'client'.

Comment: @McLovin if implementation doesn't work try the compile. The `implementation` was introduced in newer versions of Gradle as replacement for compile.

Comment: @McLovin the second error sounds suspicious, because it looks like you've opened the `client` module as project, so it's considered as root, so the `common` would need to be added as external project dependency to `client`. That would require kind of messed up additional configuration and would cause to create redundant copies of that dependency.

Comment: I added it but the problem still exists, its like it didnt change anything. Do I need main class to make a jar from a project? I only have few java classes that I want to use in other projects

Comment: Is there any clear way how to use basic java class in more than one project without copying it to both?

Comment: Yes, I open parent project in intellij (its an empty project) that has 3 gradle projects inside. common project has 3 java classes that I want to use in other two. I build a jar from common project, in other project I use 'include' and 'implementation project' for importing common jar, but then when I try to use classes from common module and build project, it removes dependency

Comment: @McLovin I've updated the answer. And just for future it's better to add module/library dependency manually to build script instead of through IDE popover, because IDE might only add the dependency to its own project configuration and not to the Gradle build files

Comment: Man, finally it works, thanks a lot for thorough explanation. You really helped me a lot!